# Having trouble with an XML file and SQL Server 2008 SSIS

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis

I'm trying to use SQL Server 2008 SSIS to read an XML file and put it into a database, but I'm having problems. Everything is green when I run debugging, but no data is actually transferred. Even when a make a simple XML Source -> Flat File output, the flat file is blank after being created.

I'm using the inline schema, but even if I remove the schema SSIS can't generate an XSD file.

Here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<DataSet>
  <xs:schema id="Schedule_x0020_Set" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="Schedule_x0020_Set" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="Schedule_x0020_Table">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="ScheduleDate" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="StaffLName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="StaffFName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="TaskName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
    <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
    <Schedule_x0020_Set>
      <Schedule_x0020_Table diffgr:id="Schedule Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
        <ScheduleDate>1/24/2011</ScheduleDate>
        <StaffLName>Smith</StaffLName>
        <StaffFName>Josh</StaffFName>
        <TaskName>Day Shift</TaskName>
      </Schedule_x0020_Table>
      <Schedule_x0020_Table diffgr:id="Schedule Table2" msdata:rowOrder="1" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
        <ScheduleDate>1/24/2011</ScheduleDate>
        <StaffLName>Doe</StaffLName>
        <StaffFName>Jane</StaffFName>
        <TaskName>Night Shift</TaskName>
      </Schedule_x0020_Table>
      <Schedule_x0020_Table diffgr:id="Schedule Table3" msdata:rowOrder="2" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
        <ScheduleDate>1/24/2011</ScheduleDate>
        <StaffLName>Johnson</StaffLName>
        <StaffFName>Barbara</StaffFName>
        <TaskName>Off</TaskName>
      </Schedule_x0020_Table>
    </Schedule_x0020_Set>
  </diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the following file to get it to work. It only began to work when I changed the schema AND removed the diffgr stuff. Hope this helps.

`<DataSet>`
`<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">`
`<xs:element name="DataSet">`
`<xs:complexType>`
`<xs:sequence>`
`<xs:element ref="Schedule_x0020_Set"/>`
`</xs:sequence>`
`</xs:complexType>`
`</xs:element>`
`<xs:element name="Schedule_x0020_Set">`
`<xs:complexType>`
`<xs:sequence>`
`<xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="Schedule_x0020_Table"/>`
`</xs:sequence>`
`</xs:complexType>`
`</xs:element>`
`<xs:element name="Schedule_x0020_Table">`
`<xs:complexType>`
`<xs:sequence>`
`<xs:element ref="ScheduleDate"/>`
`<xs:element ref="StaffLName"/>`
`<xs:element ref="StaffFName"/>`
`<xs:element ref="TaskName"/>`
`</xs:sequence>`
`</xs:complexType>`
`</xs:element>`
`<xs:element name="ScheduleDate" type="xs:string"/>`
`<xs:element name="StaffLName" type="xs:NCName"/>`
`<xs:element name="StaffFName" type="xs:NCName"/>`
`<xs:element name="TaskName" type="xs:string"/>`
`</xs:schema>`
`<Schedule_x0020_Set>`
`<Schedule_x0020_Table>`
`<ScheduleDate>1/24/2011</ScheduleDate>`
`<StaffLName>Smith</StaffLName>`
`<StaffFName>Josh</StaffFName>`
`<TaskName>Day Shift</TaskName>`
`</Schedule_x0020_Table>`
`<Schedule_x0020_Table>`
`<ScheduleDate>1/24/2011</ScheduleDate>`
`<StaffLName>Doe</StaffLName>`
`<StaffFName>Jane</StaffFName>`
`<TaskName>Night Shift</TaskName>`
`</Schedule_x0020_Table>`
`<Schedule_x0020_Table>`
`<ScheduleDate>1/24/2011</ScheduleDate>`
`<StaffLName>Johnson</StaffLName>`
`<StaffFName>Barbara</StaffFName>`
`<TaskName>Off</TaskName>`
`</Schedule_x0020_Table>`
`</Schedule_x0020_Set>`
`</DataSet>`